# vba date formatting

Tags: excel, vba, date, formatting

Been stuck on this for days now so I'm resorting to asking for assistance on this one.

I'm trying to filter between two dates in dd/mm/yyyy format ( my PC is formatted this way too in regional settings), but after I run the code, the date "custom filter" has mixed up the days and months.

Here is my code, where c3 is the start date, formatted dd/mm/yyyy, and c4 is end date, formatted dd/mm/yyyy, Sheet10.Range("a4") is the table of data, and column 34 is the column I need to apply the date filter to.

```
Dim DateBegin As Date
Dim DateEnd As Date
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Sheet10.Range("a4")
DateBegin = Format(Sheet1.Range("c3").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
DateEnd = Format(Sheet1.Range("c4").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
With Rng
.AutoFilter Field:=34, Criteria1:=">" & DateBegin, _
Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & DateEnd
```

What am I doing wrong here? Would be so grateful if somebody could help me out on this one. I've searched online for ages, but nothing I've seen has worked!

Comment: I can't test this, but what happens if you don't `Format` the values in `C3` and `C4` and just use them directly in your filter?

Comment: Maybe try `cdate(DateBegin)` and `cdate(DateEnd)` for the criteria in the autofilter ?